# P Value for Correlation greater than value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, p-value

I have a list of pearson sample correlations (r) for two variables and want to calculate a p-value to test if the two variables are highly correlated (r > 0.75 and p-value < 0.05).

H0 = r <= 0.75
Ha = r > 0.75

How do you calculate p-values when H0 is different from r = 0?

Comment: Could you clarify the apparent inconsistency between "two variables" and "list of ... correlations"?  Two variables have only one correlation, not a list of them.  The resolution of this inconsistency may be important, because testing a set of interrelated correlations is different than testing a set of independent correlations; and both procedures differ from testing a single correlation.

Comment: That depends whether one assumes independence or not.between those variables. For example, consider the contradiction inherent in assuming independent $r$-values, and then showing that the correlation between variables is significant. Has one then not disproved the assumption of independence, and if so, how can the result of significance be meaningful, i.e., significantly what?  Significantly not the correct assumption to have made? If so, what meaning does the calculation have, a null set no?